# Beamer image positioning

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning

I am trying to place two images side-by-side in a `beamer` document. However, when I compile the document, the image in the right column is forced too low on the page. I am using the `[htp]` options but no variation on these options moves the image. Is there something I am missing?

```
\begin{frame}{Frame}
    \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[htb, scale=0.3]{image1}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[htb, scale=0.3]{image2}
        \vfill
    \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: `\includegraphics` doesnt't have an `htb` key you should get an error message from that?

Comment: I am compiling in TexWorks, and I don't read all the compile text, so maybe there is a warning but I don't get an error. Is there some way to force a position using \includegraphics?

Comment: When i compile the code both images are on the same height. Please verify that your problem doesn't derive form the picture itself (like bit white area) and add a picture. Futhermore a [MEW](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/232#232) which is image independent would be helpful.

Comment: `\begin{columns}[t]` (align top by baseline) or `\begin{columns}[T]` (align top by first line). The positioning option (one of `bctT`) has to be given to the `columns` environment, not to `\inlcudegraphcis`. For details, see §12.7 (p 127) of the beamer users guide.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe depends on the images, their size or something else, but somethings like this works fine for me:

```
\begin{frame}{Frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{image1}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{image2}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

I've learned here that it's best to use `width=bla` instead of `scale`

Comment: Nope, still gives the same problem, except that the images are a bit disproportionate. I checked in inkscape and there is no white space above the top of the image.

Perhaps I should mention that there is some text in the same frame, above the two images. However, I did a test with the text removed and the problem persisted.

Comment: Can you upload the images? Or give a link to the images?

Comment: I'm just going to combine the images and include them on the frame as a single image